# Error after the installation of python-pip

Tags: pip, python-2.7

I have Ubuntu (version 18.04.4), installed on Windows, if it is important.
Python version is 2.7.17.

I'm installing pip with

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

and the output looks ok, but when I'm trying even to check the version of pip by

```
pip --version
```

I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/general_name.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.name import Name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/name.py", line 28, in <module>
    _ASN1_TYPE_TO_ENUM = dict((i.value, i) for i in _ASN1Type)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: can you try `python -m pip --version`

Comment: The same error occurs

Comment: What do you get for `python3 -V ?  (Ubuntu uses python3 for many tools, and if the version is changed many inbuilt tools will no longer operate)

Comment: I get `Python 3.6.9`, but when trying `pip3 -V` - it doesn't installed